# Can u explain below diagram is possible or not

Tags: fluid-dynamics, buoyancy, perpetual-motion

If I takes 3 balloons with same size they r connected with same thred frist end have 2 balloons and second end have 1 balloon I put same manner as shown in diagram  then frist end is gos up or not  or it can give some extra power

[image]

Comment: I didnt actually get what u say in your question?

Comment: Try making your question more clear.

Comment: You seem to be asking about an Atwood machine with balloons instead of weights. Is the question whether it helps to attach two balloons together or not?
If that's the case then yes, the more balloons you connect the more lift you are going to get!

Comment: Are you asking whether this device can produce unlimited energy? (Spoiler alert: no.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- the balloons are all of equal volume and
- are all filled with the same gas

We can conclude:

- the end with two balloons has a greater buoyant force and will rise.

If the end with a single ballon is in air and the other end in water:

- the buoyant force depends on the weight of displaced fluid, 
  so the buoyant force is greater on *each* of the submerged balloons, 
  since water is denser than air.

---

> **it can give some extra power**

**Energy**

It isn't clear what you mean by this, but it took some energy to submerge the ballons, you get some, but not all, of this energy back when you release the balloons.

Essentially you are retrieving energy you have stored in gravitational potential energy. It is converted to kinetic energy (the balloons have velocity) and heat.

You don't get any *extra*.

**Power**

Power is energy per unit time.

It isn't immediately clear that increasing the number of submerged balloons will increase the speed at which you can extract the energy you put into submerging the ballons.

It would be easier to just use a balloon with twice the volume and calculate its terminal velocity using the usual equations for friction and buoyancy - I'd simplify it by assuming the string is long enough that the balloons can achieve a terminal velocity. Otherwise it gets quite complicated and might not be very illuminating of the basic principles.

You might get more power but only for a shorter time.

---

> **Fee Energy?**

Your photo is rather poor and hard to read

[image]

I hesitate to guess what you had in mind here

See [Free Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_energy)

Comment: The end with 1 balloon is sink but what's happened when I attach 1 more balloon water pressure is higher at bottom

Comment: @user99699 - the end with one balloon sinks. It would would also sink down towards the water surface if there were only one balloon at the submerged end.

Comment: @user99699: If it isn't clear yet, it means you asked the wrong question. You need to understand the principles of bouyancy. Understanding that by reading Wikipedia or a physics textbook will be quicker than trying to deduce principles from a large number of variations of a thought experiment.

Comment: Very Thanks bro to answer sorry for my poor language